# OpenShift allow permanent external access to PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, java, openshift-online-2

I have an OpenShift gear with Nginx and PostgreSQL, and need to allow a Java applet (served from Nginx) direct access to the PG database. I've already tried to edit `~/postgresql/conf/postgresql.conf.erb.hidden`, however I don't seem to have the proper rights to change it, and can't change the environment variable `OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT` either. So does anyone have other suggestions? It's for a school assignment, and I'd prefer not having to use another server for the database, and literally can't make an API for this (part of the assignment, unfortunately).

Comment: Please learn to check if a question is appropriate on a site. Yours is [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here because a) it's not about professional usage but a school project and b) it's a development question and a better fit on [SO] anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [Openshift forums](https://forums.openshift.com/external-access-to-mysql) (and it's a security best practice):

> our firewall rules prevent connections to internal resources from anything but your application. this is by design since opening up internal resources to the world is a large security risk.

Further in given thread, a method for local forwarding is given, but it's only on your workstation.